# how to create css3 smooth transition for all browsers ?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to do smooth css3 transition animation in my web page thats not doing smooth animation in my web page but working fine in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as88425/g1kvuj71/)

Here is my code

HTML :-

```
<div class="topl" id="img">
    <img src="http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/sites/default/files/2012/12/img_logo_blue.jpg"/>
</div>
    <button>click me </button>
```

CSS :-

```
.topl {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 25%;
    width: 500px;
}
.topl img {
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.topl_1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 45px;
    left: 35px;
    right: 0;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 0 55px; 

}
.topl_1 img {
    width:160px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    transition : width .3s;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s

}
```

Jquery :-

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#img').toggleClass('topl topl_1');
});
```

Please help me out

Comment: How could we understand the question without a minimal view of your website, we can see that the animation is working in jsfiddle, but do not know the context of the page.

Comment: **note**: [Prefixing transition isn't really necessary anymore](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

Answer (score 0):

hope it can help you

http://jsfiddle.net/g1kvuj71/9/

```
 transition : width 2s;
 -webkit-transition:width 2s ;
 -moz-transition:width 2s ;
 -o-transition: width 2s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code 
http://jsfiddle.net/g1kvuj71/13/

I had just update your code. You can change position for effect

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#img').toggleClass('topl topl_1');
});
```

```css
.topl {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 11;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 top: 25%;
 width: 500px;
    transition : all .3s;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s
}
.topl img {
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;    
    transition : all .3s;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s
}
.topl_1 {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 11;
 top: 45px;
 left: 35px;
 right: 0;
 width: 160px;
 margin: 0 55px; 
    
}
.topl_1 img {
    width:160px;
    border:1px solid #000;     
    transition : all .3s;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topl" id="img">
    <img src="http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/sites/default/files/2012/12/img_logo_blue.jpg"/>
</div>
    <button>click me </button>
```